# vuejs2 get value from multi inputs with same model name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i have project working with vuejs2
this is my html code

```
<tr v-for="arrayresult , key in arrayresults">
    <td>@{{ arrayresult.item_desc_ar}}</td>
    <td><input class='form-control quantity' type='text' @input='changeQuantity()' v-model='quantity'/></td>
    <td>@{{ arrayresult.item_smallest_unit_selling_price}}</td>
    <td><a class='fa fa-trash' @click='deleteItem(arrayresult.id,key)'></a></td>
</tr>
```

and this is my vuejs2 code

```
data:{
    message:'', 
    item_search_array:false,
    arrayresults:[],
    total:0,
    quantity:1,
},
methods:{
    changeQuantity:function()
    {

    },
    deleteItem:function(key)
    {

        this.arrayresults.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

now i have this method called `changeQuantity` i need when keyup the input with model name quantity send the value and the key index to the method `changeQuantity` my problem thats they are many input with same model name `quantity` thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of each item in the `arrayresults` array as a model, then in your input, you update the particular model `model='arrayresult.qty'`.

You then can use computed properties to get the totals.

**For example:**

```js
//
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    totalQty: function () {
      var total = 0;
      this.arrayresults.forEach(item => {
        total += Number(item.qty);
      })
      return total
    },
    totalPrice: function () {
      var total = 0;
      this.arrayresults.forEach(item => {
        total += Number(item.item_smallest_unit_selling_price * item.qty);
      })
      return total
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      arrayresults:[
        {id: 1, item_desc_ar: 'A', item_smallest_unit_selling_price: 5, qty:1},
        {id: 2, item_desc_ar: 'B', item_smallest_unit_selling_price: 10, qty:1},
        {id: 3, item_desc_ar: 'C', item_smallest_unit_selling_price: 15, qty:1},
        {id: 4, item_desc_ar: 'D', item_smallest_unit_selling_price: 20, qty:1},
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Total Qty: {{totalQty}}<br>
  Total Price: {{totalPrice}}

  <table>
    <tr v-for="arrayresult , key in arrayresults">
        <td>@{{ arrayresult.item_desc_ar}}</td>
        <td><input class='form-control quantity' type='text' v-model='arrayresult.qty'/></td>
        <td>@{{ arrayresult.item_smallest_unit_selling_price}}</td>
        <td><a class='fa fa-trash' @click='deleteItem(arrayresult.id,key)'></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

p.s: also try avoid `item_`, if you think of each model in an items array as an item you dont need to include item in the property name.

Comment: no worries, you might also want to add forcing the value to an int via validation but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **object property** as **v-model** for each input.

```
<input ... v-model="quantities[input_id_iterator]" />
```

Do not forget to define quantities object in data.